# why does libpcap/tcpdump add/pad '0x00' bytes at the end of IP/TCP packets？

Tags: libpcap, tcpdump

I use both Tcpdump and libpcap(a program which uses libpcap) to capture TCP packets. And I notice there are some packets which are padded/added with additional 0x00 bytes at the end. For example, while the IP length indicated in the IP header says that the length is 40 bytes, tcpdump captures 46 bytes. and I notice there are 6 `0x00` bytes at the end of the TCP packets.

Answer (score 3):

They don't add those bytes.

The machine *sending* the packets does, because that's required on Ethernet.

A 40-byte IP packet, when sent on Ethernet, would be 54 bytes long, because there's a 14-byte Ethernet header before the IP header and payload.

However, the minimum packet length on Ethernet is 60 bytes (not including the 4-byte FCS at the end).  That means that the packet has to be padded to 60 bytes, which means adding 6 bytes of padding at the end.

(That's one reason why the IP header has a length field - so that the receiver of the packet knows how much is IP and how much is padding.)